# How to split a dictionary containing lists into equal parts based on length of the lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, split

Let's say I have a dictionary containing multiple lists of different sizes, how would I split the dictionary into 4 dictionaries of equal length based on the length of the lists. Is there a simple way of doing this?

```
dict = {"A":[1,2,3,4,5], "B":[1,2,3], "C":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
```

How would I split this into 4 dictionaries of the same length so that I get the result of:

```
dict1 = {"A":[1,2,3,4]}
dict2 = {"A":[5], "B":[1,2,3]}
dict3 = {"C":[1,2,3,4]}
dict4 = {"C":[5,6,7,8]}
```

Edit: if it couldn't be split evenly then one of the dictionaries would end up being slightly longer than the others.

Comment: And what should be the result for this input `{"A":[1,2,3,4,5], "B":[1,2,3, 4], "C":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9]}` ???

Comment: If the total length of all the lists wasnt a multiple of 4 then the one of the dictionaries would end up being slightly longer that's all. E.g. ```{"A":[1,2,3,4,5], "B":[1,2,3, 4], "C":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9]}``` would become the same except dict4 would be ```{"C":[5,6,7,8,9]}```

Comment: So it wouldn't split evenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, using a generator to yield the successive key-value pairs:

```
data = {"A":[1,2,3,4,5], "B":[1,2,3], "C":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}


def key_value_gen(data):
    # will yield ('A', 1), ('A', 2), .... ('C', 8)
    for key, values in data.items():
        for value in values:
            yield key, value

out = []
size = 4

for index, (key, value) in enumerate(key_value_gen(data)):
    # if the index is a multiple of size, we add a new dict
    if index % size == 0:
        out.append({})
    out[-1].setdefault(key, []).append(value)

print(out)
# [{'A': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, {'A': [5], 'B': [1, 2, 3]}, {'C': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, {'C': [5, 6, 7, 8]}]
```

Comment: Thanks, it isn't 100% what I want but I can easily modify it to make it work!

Answer (score 0):

Another way with just an iterative approach:

```
def group_by_count(dic, size):
    output, temp, count = [], {}, 0
    for k, v in dic.items():
        for x in v:
          if count == size:
              output.append(temp)
              temp, count = {}, 0
          temp[k] = temp.get(k, []) + [x]
          count += 1
    if temp:
        output.append(temp)
    return output

d = {"A":[1,2,3,4,5], "B":[1,2,3], "C":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
output = group_by_count(d, 4)
for dic in output:
  print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'A': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
{'A': [5], 'B': [1, 2, 3]}
{'C': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
{'C': [5, 6, 7, 8]}
```